# CloudFoundry: hello world and informations

Tags: java, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, cloud-foundry

I'm going to try this new cloud technology.

So I think the best place to start from is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcI-2V-mmmw

HelloCloud example is really nice but actually does NOT work, as it is explained in the video tutorial.

It ends up with the infamous "no mapping found for http request with uri for [/]" spring mvc error.

In addition:

- I wanna know if CloudFoundry does have a web control panel or something like that, for example, to manage MySQL service.
- Can I connect to the MySQL DB with a MySQL client and manage it?
- What about file uploads, disk quotas, bandwidth, pricing, usage? Google AppEngine does have all of these info.

I think CF is still too "beta" for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  CloudFoundry is still in beta.  All of what you are asking for is in development.  At this point, it is recommended that you try out CloudFoundry with some smaller apps, but hold off on deploying any mission critical apps until it is out of beta mode.

Comment: I have no specifics other than what I just told you.

Answer (score 0):

About the "Can I connect to the MySQL DB with a MySQL client and manage it?" question: now you can do that, using cloudfoundry caldecott tunneling capabilities:
http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/post/12928974099/now-you-can-tunnel-into-any-cloud-foundry-data-service